# Returning scope items to parent scope with $mdDialog.show()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, material-design, angular-material

Yo! I have a controller which houses a bunch of items on its `$scope`. One of the scope items, `$scope.openDialog` opens a `$mdDialog` via `$mdDialog.show()`. The object passed into `$mdDialog.show` has a template which houses controls for uploading files via the `ng-file-upload` project, which you can read about [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

I would like it if the items uploaded in the dialog window would be available in the main controller after exiting out of the dialog window. I am not sure as to whether the controller for the dialog window should reference the main `myCtrl` controller or use its own, and how to take make uploaded files available to `myCtrl`.

Here is the angular code:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngFileUpload'])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'Upload', function($scope, $mdDialog, Upload) {
  var tmpl = "<md-dialog>\n" +
    "<md-dialog-content>\n" +
    "    <input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"username\"></br></br>\n" +
    "    <input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"multiple\">upload multiple file</br></br>\n" +
    "    watching model:\n" +
    "    <div class=\"button\" ngf-select ng-model=\"files\" ngf-multiple=\"multiple\">Select File</div>\n" +
    "    on file change:\n" +
    "    <div class=\"button\" ngf-select ngf-change=\"upload($files)\" ngf-multiple=\"multiple\">Select File</div>\n" +
    "    Drop File:\n" +
    "    <div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model=\"files\" class=\"drop-box\" \n" +
    "        ngf-drag-over-class=\"dragover\" ngf-multiple=\"true\" ngf-allow-dir=\"true\"\n" +
    "        accept=\"image/*,application/pdf\">Drop pdfs or images here or click to upload</div>\n" +
    "    <div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>\n" +
    "    Image thumbnail: <img ngf-src=\"files[0]\">\n" +
    "    Files:\n" +
    "    <ul>\n" +
    "        <li ng-repeat=\"f in files\" style=\"font:smaller\">{{f.name}}</li>\n" +
    "    </ul>\n" +
    "    Upload Log:\n" +
    "    <pre>{{log}}</pre>\n" +
    "<md-action><div class=\"button\" ng-click=\"close()\">close!</div></md-action>\n" +
    "<md-action><div class=\"button\" ng-click=\"upload()\">upload!</div></md-action>\n" +
    "</md-dialog-content>\n" +
    "</md-dialog>";
$scope.files = ['files should appear here', 'files 1', 'file2'];
$scope.openDialog = function () {
  $mdDialog.show({
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        template: tmpl,
        controller: 'myCtrl'
    });
};
$scope.close = function() {
  $mdDialog.hide();
};
$scope.$watch('files', function () {
    $scope.upload($scope.files);
});
$scope.upload = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'upload/url',
                    fields: {'username': $scope.username},
                    file: file
                }).progress(function (evt) {
                    var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                    console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

BTW: As a housekeeping note, I often hear that application logic shouldn't be passed into a controller. In this situation, how would you move `$scope.upload` into a factory, given that it references `$scope` and `$scope` is not available in factories?

Thanks for the help.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/e2MYdEABhj34ahtPTO0g?p=preview

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the $scope of your controller to your $mdDialog as an example below

```
$mdDialog.show({
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    template: tmpl,
    scope: $scope,
    controller: 'myCtrl'
});
```

Check plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/0hFWEyWdetTXcPLPkbmQ?p=preview

To move application logic to factory you will be doing something like this

```
$scope.upload = factory.upload(files,$scope.username);
```

and factory will have method

```
 factory.upload = function(files,username)
 {
  function (files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'upload/url',
                fields: {'username': username},
                file: file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @cracker, please don't ask new questions in comments. That said, your question is unclear. You can show a div with either of those methods.

Answer (score 3):

setting `scope: $scope` in $mdDialog.show() will carry the scope into the modal, and `preserveScope: true` should keep the newly added elements to the $scope, otherwise it will remove them afterward?

```
$mdDialog.show({
  template: tmpl,
  scope: $scope,
  preserveScope: true,
  controller: 'myCtrl'
});
```

Comment: Did you try that out?